# Memory growing when using appendingPathComponent (class URL)

Tags: swift, memory

If I use `appendingPathComponent` in a loop without the `isDirectory` parameter the memory usage grows. If I use the `isDirectory` parameter the memory does not grow.

```
let downloadsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
for i in 1 ... 100000 {

    let myDir = downloadsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test", 
    isDirectory: true) //no memory grow

    //let myDir = downloadsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test") 
    //memory grow!!!    
}
```

Anyone know why this happens?